# ERROR: Line magic function `%matplotlib` not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have just installed IPython on a Mac (MacOS 10.7.5) following the instructions for anaconda on http://ipython.org/install.html, with no obvious errors. I now want to work my way through the example notebooks. In notebook "Part 1 - Running Code", everything works as it should until I get to

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Then I get the error message

> ERROR: Line magic function `%matplotlib` not found.

Everything after that works, except that plots, instead of appearing inline, pop up in a new window.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
import IPython
print(IPython.sys_info())
```

Does it report that you are on `'ipython_version'` 1.0+?
You might be picking up an older version of IPython that do not have the `%matplotlib` magic.

Comment: Since @LeonAvery mentioned he is a newbie it is worth mentioning that `Import` should be `import`.

Comment: Thanks, Greg -- I made that mistake but figured it out for myself :-)

It's version 0.13.2. So I guess anaconda doesn't yet have 1.0.0. I see where I can download that, but I'm not sure how to install it. Do I just unzip it and 'cd <folder>; python setup.py'? Will conda get confused about what I have installed?

Comment: Consider `print(IPython.sys_info())` in Python3

Comment: I am using Jupyter Notebook with ipython version 7.0.1, but same error appears  to me.

Comment: I had to issue the `pip3 install --upgrade ipython` command since the version installed was 5.5 for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

If you have Anaconda, just do `conda update ipython` from the command line. No need for removal, easy_install and all the rest.

Answer (score 5):

if you run the notebook through shell, try the command

```
ipython notebook --pylab=inline
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your code is wrong:
`%matplotlib.inline`

The correct one is:
`%matplotlib inline`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on Windows, but I believe it will work the same way:

1. Get rid of the old IPython. The command is `conda remove ipython`.
2. Get [`easy_install`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) if you don't have it. Follow the instructions to install `easy_install` for your system.
3. Use `easy_install` to reinstall the newest IPython. The command is `easy_install ipython[all]`, just like it shows on the site.

With Conda's default IPython gone, it should indicate it's loading IPython 1.0.0. You can make sure by running either IPython or the IPython Notebook and running the command `%lsmagic`. If `matplotlib` is in the list, you've got it.

Comment: You should provide the link for the OP to get `easy_install` rather than just telling him what to google.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the notebook through shell, try the command

```
ipython notebook --pylab=inline
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure, you use the right installation of ipython

In my case, I have system-wide Python installation for application development and beside that, also anaconda for data analysis (to be used with `ipython` notebooks).

When starting `ipython` notebook, I shall set `PATH` properly to use anaconda version of `ipython`.

Forgetting to set `PATH`, I use system-wide installed `ipython` which does not serve running notebooks well resulting in the complain about `%matplotlib inline` as noted in OP.

When I set `PATH` properly and used anaconda version of python and `ipython`, all goes well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on windows.
*Make sure that you've added Conda and python to the path.* To check that you can run the following command on command prompt

`jupyter notebook`

if it doesnt recognize then go to anaconda prompt and type

`where conda`
`where python`

refer the image for paths to include
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeA5d.png

Add these to the path and mostly youll be good to go

Answer (score -1):

instead of the inline command, I simply put this after the plot 
`matplotlib.pyplot.show()`