# Error: Line magic function

Tags: python, ipython, canopy, ipython-magic

I'm trying to read a file using python and I keep getting this error

```
ERROR: Line magic function `%user_vars` not found.
```

My code is very basic just

```
names = read_csv('Combined data.csv')
names.head()
```

I get this for anytime I try to read or open a file. I tried using this thread for help.

[ERROR: Line magic function `%matplotlib` not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175798/error-line-magic-function-matplotlib-not-found)

I'm using enthought canopy and I have IPython version 2.4.1.  I made sure to update using [the IPython installation page](http://ipython.org/install.html) for help. I'm not sure what's wrong because it should be very simple to open/read files. I even get this error for opening text files.

EDIT:

I imported traceback and used

```
 print(traceback.format_exc())
```

But all I get is none printed. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: You don't have IPython version 2.7.9. You have *Python* version 2.7.9. The latest version in IPython's 2.x series was 2.4.1, then it jumped to 3.0. Please [edit] your question to indicate the exact version of IPython you're using.

Comment: Probably it won't apply to everyone but I just got this error after Kernel got crushed.(forcing to close `pythonw` using task manager). So I closed and reopened the Canopy and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Pandas. Try the following (assuming your csv file is in the same path as the your script lib) and insert it one line at a time if you are using the IPython Shell:

```
import pandas as pd 
names = pd.read_csv('Combined data.csv')
names.head()
```