# Line magic function `%store` not found

Tags: python, scrapy, ipython, virtualenv, storemagic

I am using iPython with Scrapy shell inside a virtualenv, but I can't save my project's variables (they get deleted everytime I leave the project) and [%store](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.12/config/extensions/storemagic.html) won't work, returning "Line magic function `%store` not found".

Currently, I have Python 2.7.12, iPython 5.7.0 and Scrapy 1.5.0, all working inside a virtualenv.

There are some questions here about similar errors, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735624/error-line-magic-function), but I could not find a solution regarding storemagic/persistence specifically. Maybe this issue I am facing has something to do with running it from a virtual environment?

I would like to add persistence to those variables, so they can later be called from a Scrapy spider. Reading the iPython documentation, I figured out storemagic was the way to do it, but it won't work for me inside Scrapy shell. Is there another way to do that?

I can't figure out what's going on, would appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: And other magics do work?

Comment: They do, not %store though. I am trying to call those variables from a Scrapy spider, but it won't recognize them saying they are not defined. Maybe an option is to save them in a CSV file or something like that?

Comment: Can't figure out why %store is not working though... I am only running the whole thing from a virtualenv because it is the recommendation in the Scrapy documentation.